# create new df column based on grouping and conditions in PYTHON

Tags: python, sorting, conditional-statements, grouping

my dataframe looks like the bottom and i want to create a new column called "remove" that would be true/false based on the following conditions.

i only want to keep one row for each "url" and want to determine which to keep based on this order:

- keep the one with a higher score
- if score is same then go to track "gre" and "tca" are favored over "oke"
- if they are equal at the track then go to "size" and take the bigger one

I would like the new column to be true or false based on if it should be removed or not.

thanks in advance!!

|  | name | age | track | score | size | url | url_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | timmy | 10 | gre | 0.982 | 41 | target.com | 2 |
| 1 | chester | 12 | tca | 0.251 | 12 | michaels.com | 3 |
| 2 | trixie | 10 | oke | 0.0879 | 15 | macys.com | 2 |
| 3 | aj | 9 | gre | 0.985 | 20 | michaels.com | 3 |
| 4 | cosmo | 150 | tca | 0.982 | 328 | target.com | 2 |
| 5 | wanda | 145 | gre | 0.879 | 550 | macys.com | 2 |
| 6 | jorgen | 500 | oke | 0.432 | 51 | michaels.com | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sort_values` with your sort criteria and a `custom_sort` as the key re-order your rows with the first being the highest ranked. Then we use `duplicated` on only the `url` column to flag all but the first instance of a url as to be removed:

```
def custom_sort(x):
    if x.name == 'track':
        return x.map({'gre': 0, 'tca': 0, 'oke': 1})
    
    else:
        return x

df['remove'] = df.sort_values(['url', 'score', 'track', 'size'], key = custom_sort, ascending = False).duplicated(subset = 'url')
```

Comment: this worked thank you! would you be able to tell me what x represents in the function please?

Comment: You can read up on [key functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions), but in short, it returns a number so the sorter knows how to sort it. Without a key, the sort would just be alphabetical, but using `custom_sort` as a key function, I can implement your desired order to the track. For `df.sort_values` there is an additional wrinkle in that the key function has to work on each of the columns inputted as a Series. You can explore this behavior by seeing what `custom_sort(df['url'])` or `custom_sort(df['track'])` does.